# Override Point3D(double,double,double) to Point3D(single,single,single)

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, overriding

I am developing on WPF .NET4.5 an application which shows on screen 3D objects that are stored in a .STL file. In .stl positions, normals, etc. are stored as float (Single), but the native format of the 3D models in WPF is with double precision.

**The problem:** I load big amounts of data - 1 object x 2 600 000 triangles + 16 objects x ~150 000 triangles. When all are loaded the application takes ~3GB of RAM and seems to be very unstable.

**Question:** Can I somehow override the Point3D and Vector3D classes, so that they store the coordinates in float? And make the native WPF 3D system use them without complaining? I think this might make the application use less RAM.
I see that the Point3D is a struct rather than a class. Does this help me or not?

**My idea:** I was thinking of making my own myPoint3D struct from scratch, which has everything from Point3D (attribs, funcs, operators, etc.). Then creating myPoint3DCollection and somehow making MeshGeometry3D use them instead. Of course the same gymnastics apply for Vector3D, because of the Normals.

Comment: I would think of a different concept. Do you really need to store such a huge amount of data in the RAM?

Comment: Is there really another option? I load my Mesh object's data and I guess .NET does the rest, store the data for use in the RAM. Otherwise it would not be able to use it on demand or as quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, assuming you don't want to reinvent the whole thing.

The only option I can think of to make WPF accept your custom point struct, is implementing an implicit conversion in the struct. This doesn't help, though, as the conversion will again create a `Point3D` with the according memory consumption.

Deriving and masking doesn't work, as `Point3D` is a struct. Even if it was a class, you would depend on the properties being virtual in `Point3D` to actually override them in your subclass. Even then, as soon as the property would be used and you would return a single converted as a double, the 64bit memory for a double would be allocated, as it is a value type and therefore not passed as a pointer, but as *real* copy on the stack. So plenty of reasons it doesn't work.

I would head in a different direction and simplify your model to a reasonable size. You could merge triangles and probably reduce the size of the model significantly: One triangle with an edge length of x is the same area as four triangles of edge length 0.5x, meaning that a linear increase of the visually relevant element (triangle) area is quadratically reducing the number of nodes (points).

Not sure whether this is a valid approach in your case...

Comment: A thought this was the situation, but still I needed to be sure. It's pity though, as such a thing would boost WPF 3D performance 200%. In the end we'll go with 3Ds' _ProOptimizer_ to lessen the number of polygons. Thank you very much!

Comment: @M.Aldimirov: You're very welcome. If the answer resolved the question for you, please mark it as solved. This will get you and me some rep and let others know that there is no more effort to spend here ;) Cheers!